# How can I set validity of a Web Application?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, web-applications, licensing

I have my web Application developed in Java EE using Spring, Hibernate. In some cases I have to handover client source code with database but with a condition he can run application for the time period of 1 year only but the problem is client is having code so but obviously he can modify and make it working.!! So is there any scope for encryption/decryption or code Obfuscation or some other way??

Comment: Think about sell your support to your customer, instead of only the code.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can make it harder for your client, but if he has the (even obfuscated and/or encrypted) code *and* must have a possibility to run it, you're out of luck, since the latter will entail that the JVM must have the "cleartext" in some sense.

Generally, *any* setup where the cipher is present along with the cleartext is prone to some form of attack, be it differential crypto or otherwise...

You should concentrate on delivering value to your client, then he'll inevitably come back for more business.